# why use cells.value in vba? I tried to use cells without value, it also worked

Tags: excel, cells, vba

For the two following lines,

```
Sheet1.Cells(1,1)=7
Sheet1.Cells(2,1).value=7
```

These two lines of codes works exactly the same. Why do we even use Cells.value then?

Comment: Most objects have a default property.  `Value` is the default property for a Cell.  I prefer `Sheet1.Cells(2,1).Value` because I prefer to be absolutely explicit.  If you never rely on defaults, you will never be surprised by the default not being what you expect.

Comment: Thank you, that's very clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR To not be ambiguous**

When You write `Sheet1.Cells(1,1)` you are receiving a range object.  The default property for that object is `Value`, so when you try to write to that range, it defaults to the value property.  Using the `Value` property explicitly can prevent confusion later on, particularly if you are also using other properties of that range, such as `Formula`, `FormulaR1C1`, `Value2`, ...